# AngularJS : Multipage Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, frontend

It's almost a month learning angularjs. What I have understood till now is that angularjs forces you to create SPA's though you can create multiple page application/website as well but I don't know how as I don't find good examples out there. Even angularjs seed projects are using SPA concept.

By multiple page website some questions I need answers are:

1. Will Multipage application able to handle query params just like SPA easily? if yes then how? i.e would we use ngRoute or something else?
2. Until now I have concluded that there is no way of communicating two controllers if they are on separate pages other than using localStorage, sessionStorage or cookies. Right?
3. Will we able to handle global events across multiple pages? i.e. If two tabs are open and on 1st tab user logs out, will on second page I can get event notification? (Well I am sure yes, but experts can better tell)

Although SPA is easy to implement (well for my case) and makes HTML fragment easy to handle, but I don't have that case right now as it's not application that I am building, I have complex site that SPA is not the right fit. In short I don't want to use ng-view. So please guide with examples if possible.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't use ng-view, then $route is almost useless. You will have to handle param manually in that case
2. You are right.
3. Not possible to communicate between two tabs by angularjs. Angularjs will be instantiated independently in two tabs. You will have to maintain it from server end to the opened tabs

Comment: 1. I think there must be other way other than handling manually.
2. thanks.
3. why? can't we use $broadcast and $on events?

Comment: 1. Maybe :)  3. Well, $broadcast or $emit only work with a single prototypical inherited scope chain. But when you open it in the two tabs, there will be two different prototypical inherited scopes.  That means two set of angular apps, scope, injector all things. How will it be communicate?

Comment: 3. you have a good point in that. thanks. but the first question is the most biggest problem for me right now.